# filtering a category in dotcover

Tags: nunit, filtering, categories, dotcover

I understand that you can filter projects, classes and methods but is it possible to filter a category in dotcover.
I am using nuit as my unit tester.
Please help!
Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 1):

Peter, you're right, you can't do that via coverage filters in dotCover, but still you can specify categories to include or exclude in nunit console runner ([documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6))

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from the command line. Just set **/include:MyCategoryName** as the first argument in TargetArguments, followed by the target dll(s).

```
dotcover.exe analyse coverage.config.xml
```

coverage.config.xml looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
    <TargetExecutable>Thirdparty\NUnit-2.5.10.11092\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe</TargetExecutable>
    <TargetArguments>/include:MyCategoryName bin/release/MyAssemblyUnderTest.dll
    </TargetArguments>
    <TargetWorkingDir>.</TargetWorkingDir>
    ...
```

Tip: It helps if you have the location of dotcover.exe in your Environment Variables --> Path Variable.

For more info on [running dotcover from the command line](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/running-code-coverage-from-the-console-with-dotcover/)